# Node: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Last Node project. When I try to access the server from the browser, it crashes and I get: "cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at ReadFileContext.callback". The server runs from the 'index.js' file fine, up until I try to access it from the browser. Not sure what it means. Hopefully, I am getting this error because I simply misspelled something.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

const json = fs.readFileSync( `${__dirname}/data/data.json`, 'utf-8' );

// parses through the JSON file, returns a JS object, stores the object
const laptopData = JSON.parse(json);

const server = http.createServer( function(request, response) {
 
 // (1) we parse (read line-by-line) through the URL OBJECT, inside the object is the REQUEST OBJECT, inside that object is the value of the URL we typed into the BROWSER, we use 'true' so it returns an object,we only want the value of the URLs pathname property, lastly we store that value into a container: pathName
 const pathName = url.parse(request.url, true).pathname;
 
 // (2) we parse through the url object to get the value of the 'query' property
 const id = url.parse(request.url, true).query.id;
 
 // if the value of pathName is '/products'
 if (pathName === '/products' || pathName == '/') {
  
  // (1) our response will be a header
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html' });
 
  // (2) this is the response
  response.end('This is the PRODUCTS page.'); //'This is the PRODUCTS page.'
 
 // if the value of pathName is '/laptop'
 } else if (pathName === '/laptop' && id < laptopData.length) {
      
  // (1) our response will be a header
  // the first value is the HTTP STATUS CODE that is displayed
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html' });
 
  // stores the HTML into the 'data' para
  fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/templates/template-laptop.html`, 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
  
   // used to clean up the code
   const laptop = laptopData[id];
   
   // replaces all of the placeholders
   let output = data.replace(/{%PRODUCTNAME%}/g, laptop.productName);
   
   output = output.replace(/{%IMAGE%}/g, laptop.image);
   output = output.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, laptop.price);
   output = output.replace(/{%SCREEN%}/g, laptop.screen);
   output = output.replace(/{%CPU%}/g, laptop.cpu);
   output = output.replace(/{%STORAGE%}/g, laptop.storage);
   output = output.replace(/{%RAM%}/g, laptop.ram);
   output = output.replace(/{%DESCRIPTION%}/g, laptop.description);
   
   response.end(output);
  
  });
 
 // if the value of pathName is neither '/products' nor '/laptop' nor empty
 } else {
  
  // (1) our response will be a header
  response.writeHead(400, { 'Content-type': 'text/html' });
 
  // (2) this is the response
  response.end('URL was not ground on the server!');
         
 };

});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
 console.log('Server is working.'); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline|Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Apple Macbook Pro 2018 /// The Laptop Store!</title>

    <style>
        *,
        *::before,
        *::after {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        html {
            font-size: 62.5%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            padding: 6rem 4rem 10rem;
            line-height: 1.7;
            font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
            color: #555;
            min-height: 100vh;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #67b26f, #4ca2cd);
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: "Bungee Inline", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 6rem;
            color: white;
            transform: skewY(-5deg);
            margin-bottom: 6rem;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            word-spacing: 3px;
        }

        h1::before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            height: 65%;
            width: 58%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 105%;
            left: 50%;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #67b26f, #4ca2cd);
            opacity: .8;
            z-index: -1;
            transform: skewY(370deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .container {
            width: 110rem;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .laptop {
            width: 70rem;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: white;
            box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            position: relative;
        }

        .laptop__hero {
            position: relative;
        }

        .laptop__hero::before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #67b26f, #4ca2cd);
            opacity: .4;
        }

        .laptop__img {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        .laptop__price {
            position: absolute;
            top: -3rem;
            right: -3rem;
            z-index: 100;
            background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #67b26f, #4ca2cd);
            height: 14rem;
            width: 14rem;
            border: 6px solid white;
            border-radius: 50%;
            transform: rotate(15deg);
            box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            color: white;
            font-size: 3rem;
            font-family: "Bungee Inline", sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .laptop__back:link,
        .laptop__back:visited {
            position: absolute;
            top: 2rem;
            left: 2rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            z-index: 1;
            border: 2px solid white;
            border-radius: 100rem;
            padding: 0 2rem;
            transition: all .3s;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .laptop__back:hover,
        .laptop__back:active {
            background-color: white;
            color: #555;
        }

        .laptop__name {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #67b26f, #4ca2cd);
            padding: 1.75rem 1rem;
            font-family: "Bungee Inline", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 3.25rem;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            word-spacing: 2px;
        }

        .laptop__details {
            background-color: #eee;
            padding: 4rem 6rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-gap: 1.75rem;
        }

        .laptop__description {
            padding: 5rem 6rem;
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            line-height: 1.8;
        }

        .laptop__link:link,
        .laptop__link:visited {
            display: block;
            background-color: #5aaa9d;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            transition: all .3s;
        }

        .laptop__link:hover,
        .laptop__link:active {
            background-color: #67b26f;
        }

        .laptop__source {
            padding: 0 6rem 3rem;
            color: #999;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }

        .laptop__source a:link,
        .laptop__source a:visited {
            color: #999;
        }

        .laptop__source a:hover,
        .laptop__source a:active {
            color: #555;
        }

        .emoji-left {
            font-size: 2rem;
            margin-right: 1rem;
        }

        .emoji-right {
            font-size: 2rem;
            margin-left: 1rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>The Laptop Store!</h1>
        <figure class="laptop">
            <p class="laptop__price">${%PRICE%}</p>
            <a href="overview.html" class="laptop__back"><span class="emoji-left"></span>Back</a>
            <div class="laptop__hero">
                <img src="${%IMAGE%}" alt="${%PRODUCTNAME%}" class="laptop__img">
            </div>
            <h2 class="laptop__name">${%PRODUCTNAME%}</h2>
            <div class="laptop__details">
                <p><span class="emoji-left"></span> ${%SCREEN%}</p>
                <p><span class="emoji-left"></span> ${%CPU%}</p>
                <p><span class="emoji-left"></span> ${%STORAGE%}</p>
                <p><span class="emoji-left"></span> ${%RAM%}</p>
            </div>
            <p class="laptop__description">${%DESCRIPTION%}</p>
            <p class="laptop__source">Source: <a href="https://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/laptops/best-laptops-1304361"
                    target="_blank">https://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/laptops/best-laptops-1304361</a></p>
            <a href="#" class="laptop__link">${%PRICE%} <span class="emoji-right"> </span></a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not a string (as indicated by the error message).

This means, most likely, there was an error. You are not looking at the error parameter `error`. You should check that to be sure you are getting a valid result before processing `data`.

Outputting the error will also give you information about how it is breaking.